Apartment Gem + Rails 7
I'm trying to install apartment gem but its giving error.
When I do
bundle exec rails generate apartment:install

it produce error
 undefined method `new' for "Apartment::Reloader":String (NoMethodError)

what the solution of this issue?

what's the apartment version you have installed?

here the gem i installed.
gem 'apartment', git: 'git@github.com:influitive/apartment.git', branch: "development"

Actually apartment doesn't support rails 6 and so on.
Use below gem instead:
gem 'ros-apartment', require: 'apartment'

and then do:
bundle install

This resolved my issue.
